# nodejs sftp.get call with encoding

Tags: node.js, encoding, sftp

I am using the ssh2-sftp-client package for Node.js.
I am trying to make an sftp call to get a file with a specific encoding.
I am able to get the file when I do not use any encoding:

```
var config = {
        host: urls,
        port: port,
        user: user,
        password: password,
      };
let sftp = new Client;
sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
sftp.get(file)
.then((response) => {My Code});
}
```

The encoding is incorrect.
According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client/v/2.1.1), I can specify the encoding the file will arrive in:

```
sftp.get(remoteFilePath, [useCompression], [encoding], [addtionalOptions]);
```

When I try to add the encoding:

```
sftp.get(file,[false],["iso-8859-1"])
```

I get an error message:

```
wtr.once('error', (err) => {
              ^
TypeError: wtr.once is not a function
```

I tried to add without the array brackets:

```
sftp.get(file,false,"iso-8859-1")
```

But that doesn't work either.

How can I specify the encoding of the file when I make the call?

Thank you